# Trying to input a formatted text file and get rid of all white spaces in addition to getting every word on a separate line in perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $inFile, '<', 'electricity.txt') or die $!;

while (<$inFile>) {
  chomp $_;
  $_ = split(/\s+/);
  print $_;
}
close ($inFile);
```

When I run this, I get a bunch of numeric values as the output. I'm not sure why.

Comment: What does `split` return?

Comment: Hmm so if used on a scaler it returns the number of fields which found and returns them in an array.  In an array context it returns a list of fields which found. Which means i need to be using an array instead of a scaler! I think.. lol

Comment: Yup! Assign it to an array variable. Then figure out how to print each element on its own line.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using 'substitution' instead of the 'split'. Not sure how it works on here should I post my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you intended to write as following

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

open my $inFile, '<', 'electricity.txt' 
    or die $!;

while( <$inFile> ) {
  chomp;
  say for split;
}

close ($inFile);
```

NOTE: [$_](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators) is not intended for assignment, [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) in *list* context returns list/array of elements, otherwise it returns size of the *list*/*array*

NOTE: `split` and `split ' '` is [special case](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) for `split /\s+/`

TutorialPoint: [Perl - Special Variables](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_special_variables.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it this way...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;



open (my $inFile, '<', 'electricity.txt') or die $!;

while (my $lines = <$inFile>) {

  chomp $lines;
    $lines =~ s/\s+/\n/g;
  print $lines;

  foreach my $line (split /\s+/, $lines) {
        $count{$line}++;
    }



}
close ($inFile);
```

Comment: What `%count` is for if you do not use it at all?

Answer (score 0):

> In your Answer code you have forget to declare the `%count` hash variable. Hence sure you will get the compilation error while booting your code. Just I will check in my way how can I get the answer in your question.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %count = ();

my @text = split /\s+/,  do { local $/; <DATA> };

$count{$_}++ for(@text);

print Dumper \%count;
print join "\n", @text;
```

**I will get the output from the above code. My Question is, how can I merge two line of the codes in a single line. Someone please advice. I tried but I couldn't get the output.**

```
__DATA__
We study six natural decompositions of mixed states in one spatial dimension:
```

Comment: What `%count` for is? Do you count words?